# Why am I getting an empty string from calls to IO::Socket::INET->peerhost?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a small script to monitor if certain ports are attempted to be accessed on my Linux box (Centos 6) using Perl 5.10.1. I'm getting back blank entries for my peerhost request. I'm not sure why. It sounds like it may be a failure in the IO socket module (http://snowhare.com/utilities/perldoc2tree/example/IO/Socket.html) but I'm not really sure. Any insight would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Since I enabled the strict and warnings I'm getting an 'uninitialized value $display' in the cases where I thought it was blank.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket;
use Sys::Syslog qw( :DEFAULT setlogsock);
use threads;

my @threads=();
my @ports=(88,110,389);

main(\@ports);

sub main
{
    my $ports=shift;
    setlogsock('unix');
    openlog($0,'','user');
    for my $port (@{$ports} ) {
        push @threads, threads->create(\&create_monitor, $port );
    }
    $_->join foreach @threads;
    closelog;
# wait for all threads to finish
}


sub create_monitor{
    my $LocalPort=shift;

    my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
        LocalPort => $LocalPort,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Listen => 1,
        Reuse => 1,
        ) or die "Could not create socket: $!\n";


    while(1)
    {
        my $peer_connection= $sock->accept;
        my $display = $peer_connection->peerhost();
        my $message="Connection attempt on port $LocalPort from $display";
        #syslog('info', $message);
        print $message."\n";
    }

}
```

NOTE - it is intentional that this script never finish. I'll eventually wrap this with an init script and have it run as a service.

Comment: Put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of the script. You script contains some errors that you should fix first. Also, the shebang may be  invalid. Also, your loop will never finish, as it doesn't have a termination condition. Therefore, your threads will never join.

Answer (score 1):

Perl `accept()` has an error code like most other functions. For `accept()` it is a false return, see also [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/accept.html).

So when you get undefined as result there is an error in `accept()` call. The error of accept is saved in the errno variable ($!).

Same is true for `peerhost()` (see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html)). It also can fail and return an error code.

If you only use the above code without anything else, then probably you reach connection limit of your system (you should close the connections) when `accept()` fails. See `rlimit()` to find out how that number can be increased.

One case where `peerhost()` fails may be that remote connection was closed already.

Comment: He said `$display` (the return from `->peerhost`) is undefined, not `$peer_connection` (the return from `accept`).  So I do not think this answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry. Forget to add that peerhost() is the same. I don't know what it actually calls, but probably getpeername(). This can also fail and will also return its error code in $!. So I suggest to simply have a look at the error code and check if it sounds reasonable. I don't remember exactly what situation causes this, but my sources all have a check for failures of that call.

Comment: Fixed the text accordingly.

Comment: OK, better.  Still, pretty strange for `getpeername` to fail on a socket just returned from `accept`.  I am not sure you are right that it can fail just because the other end has closed the connection...  Local resources for the descriptor are still around until you close your end; no reason for those not to include the peer's address.  But still a good suggestion.  +1

Comment: When first confronted with this topic years ago I thought the same. But there are cases when this is not true. I did find a man page for getpeername() yesterday, which explicitely documented it, but don't find it again. Maybe usually it happens only when the connection handshake is done only partial, so the host cannot be sure the peer address is really correct. Never investigated it in that detail :-)